# How to interpret probability of an outcome in a multivariable logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, multivariate-analysis

I am modeling a binary outcome with multivariable logistic regression, where all predictors have been found significant, but I am particularly interested in one (continuous) predictor.

I would like to plot/make conclusions about the probability of the outcome as a function of this predictor. How do I take into account the other predictors when I try to make a plot or an interpretation of the result?

Comment: Binary logistic regression is a multivariable method, not a multivariate one.  Multivariate refers to having multiple dependent variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your purpose. I assume we are dealing with marginal effects here (because of the change in the probability of the outcome for a change in the predictor). When marginal effect is computed for a predictor ($x_k$), other predictors are held at specific values. So, you can keep other predictors at the mean. Or, if you have substantive interest in specific values of these predictors, you can use those values too. Whatever you prefer, the main idea is the same for a marginal change (which is an effect of infinitely small change in $x_k$):

$$\frac{\delta\text{Pr}(y=1|x=x^*)}{\delta x_k}$$

where $x^*$ could be means of other predictors, contain specific values of predictors, or equal $x_i$ with the observed values for the $i$th observation. In each case, the interpretation would be different based on your analysis.

---

Long, J. Scott. 1997. *Regression Models for Categorical and Limited Dependent Variables*. Thousand Oaks London New Delhi: SAGE Publications, Inc.

Comment: Elasticity (first derivative as above) is only used in econometrics as far as I can see.  Instead, vary one variable at a time and plot it against the predicted probability.  I go into this in detail in my _Regression Modeling Strategies_ [book and course notes](http://fharrell.com/links).